# Would cross partition query in cosmos db be helpful if we know one part of it

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using cosmos db for our data storage and there is a case where I have to do cross partition query because I don't know the specific partition key. But I will know a part of it.

To elaborate, my partition key is combination of multiple strings, lets say A-B.

and lets say I only know A  but not B. So is there any way to do wild card searching on the partition key.
would that optimize the query or its not possible. Depending on that I will consider if to put A in the the partition key at all or not

Answer (score 0):

Based on my researching and [Partitioning in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview), nowhere mentions cosmos db partition key supports wildcard searching feature. Only index policy supports wildcard setting:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#including-and-excluding-property-paths

So,for your situation,you don't know B so that i'd suggest you considering setting pk as A. Besides,you could vote up this thread:https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB/issues/153